# Append to an empty list using a single line for-loop python

Tags: list, python-3.x, append

I am trying to append numbers from a generator to an empty list using a single line for loop but it returns `None`. I understand it can be done using a for loop with 2 lines but I was wondering what I am missing. i.e.,

`>>> [].append(i) for i in range(10)`

`[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

I was hoping to create this in one line:

`>>> [].append(i) for i in range(10)`

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write a proper comprehension, without append.

```
>>> [i for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(i for i in range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding Explanation as to what happens,
Append doesn't  return anything,

```
y = []
x = [y.append(i) for i in range(10)]
print(x)
print(y)
```

produces

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also just cast a range which is a iterable:

```
list(range(10))
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

also for numpy users:

```
np.arange(10)
>>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

or you can use linspace if its more understandable to you (linspace(from,to,pieces)) :

```
np.linspace(0,9,10)
>>> array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

Answer (score -2):

y = []

[y.append(i) for i in range(10)]

print(y)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66415494/2227743).